# sudo apt-get update getting connection timed out error in Linux 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt

I'm getting below error when sudo apt-get update

```
Err:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease        
  Could not connect to 185.46.212.88:80 (185.46.212.88), connection timed out
Err:2 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                           
  Could not connect to 185.46.212.88:80 (185.46.212.88), connection timed out
Err:3 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease              
  Could not connect to 185.46.212.88:80 (185.46.212.88), connection timed out
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                        
  Could not connect to 185.46.212.88:80 (185.46.212.88), connection timed out
Err:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
  Could not connect to 185.46.212.88:80 (185.46.212.88), connection timed out
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                
  Unable to connect to 185.46.212.88:80:
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to 185.46.212.88:80:
```

........
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: As you can notice yourself, you can't connect to the repos.

Comment: I'm not good at this, could you please help me how to do??

Comment: You have some network issue. Are you connected to internet?

Comment: if i ping i'm not seeing any issues

`ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.163.174) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from maa05s05-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.163.174): icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=24.7 ms
64 bytes from maa05s05-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.163.174): icmp_seq=3 ttl=117 time=41.3 ms
64 bytes from maa05s05-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.163.174): icmp_seq=4 ttl=117 time=31.3 ms`

Comment: Is your computer behind a proxy server? I'm almost sure about it because 172.... is a private IP range. google.com does not have that IP.

Comment: @turbulence no i guess

Comment: May be is has been set by error. Could you please "echo $HTTP_PROXY" and "echo $http_proxy"

Comment: both commands showing  empty

Comment: Ok, then please check "sudo iptables-save". Here you can see any network forwarding.

Comment: this one also showing empty result

Comment: Another strange thing is that according to the above error, all urls are resolved to same IP. You can try by changing your configured DNS server. You can try one of Google's open DNS server: 8.8.8.8

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1262746/edit) to show us the complete output of `ping -4 -c3 ppa.launchpad.net`

Comment: @turbulence yes i edit the resolve file and added nameserver 8.8.8.8
and 8.8.4.4 but still no use

Comment: @user535733 i'm getting this error
ping: invalid option -- '4'
Usage: ping [-aAbBdDfhLnOqrRUvV] [-c count] [-i interval] [-I interface]
            [-m mark] [-M pmtudisc_option] [-l preload] [-p pattern] [-Q tos]
            [-s packetsize] [-S sndbuf] [-t ttl] [-T timestamp_option]
            [-w deadline] [-W timeout] [hop1 ...] destination

Comment: Then omit the `-4`

Comment: @user535733
PING ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- ppa.launchpad.net ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2041ms

Comment: That's the correct server (91.189.95.83), and it's up. However, your original output said that you were trying to connect to 185.46.212.88 instead. Any idea why it's different?  This is why turbulence had you rule out a bad DNS. Sure looks to me like you are behind some kind of proxy. @Pilot6 is right - you have some network issue that does not seem related to Ubuntu. Are you on a home network? Or some Corporate or School network?